# Scaling issues using seaborn 2D kde plotting in jupyter notebooks in vscode

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, kdeplot

I am having an issue using any type of 2D kde plotting in seaborn. The y axis seems to be scaled very off.

I am running this on vscode in a jupyter notebook using the most recent version of seaborn

For example here's a joint plot I made using the following code

```
sns.jointplot( data=df,x='shear', y='sat_norm')
```

[image]

If I added kind='kde' I get the following plot

[image]

Here is the dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'shear': {2926: 19.975084119123906,
  2927: 37.18992996260234,
  2928: 51.65416419774487,
  2929: 21.366039009849093,
  2930: 25.88113171541938,
  2931: 22.003321443992395,
  2932: 31.496004487542184,
  2933: 22.806658663854996,
  2934: 18.263753872890693,
  2935: 21.843535334409005,
  2936: 22.251521128568648,
  2937: 17.453526457774004,
  2938: 26.235506324206867,
  2939: 26.08460755717408,
  2940: 21.01288945206868,
  2941: 25.33981656045819,
  2942: 49.85884696525539,
  2943: 19.061595197518667,
  2944: 22.055520930078348,
  2945: 16.054620367398364,
  2946: 26.066791106216126,
  2947: 22.236281781977116,
  2948: 37.80238579544662,
  2949: 51.94723853020805,
  2950: 22.702581581004345,
  2951: 24.4522078028404,
  2952: 17.41624216049658,
  2953: 67.09339642489113,
  2954: 21.96540029445359,
  2955: 24.233579977649505,
  2956: 25.20795121022604,
  2957: 21.6562261240387,
  2958: 27.0494142444042,
  2959: 17.54011287370428,
  2960: 18.697396725806808,
  2961: 49.02470441232235,
  2962: 28.02949303327629,
  2963: 22.674408982927357,
  2964: 26.819193426295584,
  2965: 18.68829418353226,
  2966: 20.292178837509542,
  2967: 23.234931682849908,
  2968: 29.397400989980607,
  2969: 19.95402826389817,
  2970: 24.957673090371784,
  2971: 17.22794143393881,
  2972: 27.22918907908201,
  2973: 16.529767400405497,
  2974: 42.68947747724305,
  2975: 18.83595171533085,
  2976: 64.61656348219817,
  2977: 23.2121326465775,
  2978: 21.816822597662988,
  2979: 23.761938954618433,
  2980: 22.3746860746278,
  2981: 26.600268661739896,
  2982: 21.29366923486611,
  2983: 18.870637650525715,
  2984: 18.0135587737032,
  2985: 28.579495906843647,
  2986: 23.08910506826203,
  2987: 16.991256497257385,
  2988: 21.910669873428414,
  2989: 22.745460577656054,
  2990: 28.087960913333255,
  2991: 24.593572667309093,
  2992: 23.68344996824954,
  2993: 19.56258466373067,
  2994: 20.729275751863117,
  2995: 31.123352426565056,
  2996: 22.69929042259365,
  2997: 17.368592485355563,
  2998: 14.627810074160967,
  2999: 28.823280792433035,
  3000: 19.754066305436545,
  3001: 23.324700614940532,
  3002: 26.47495965529144,
  3003: 21.16875134159095,
  3004: 27.760959873292258,
  3005: 14.348219278854636,
  3006: 30.20594854688264,
  3007: 22.817925468969722,
  3008: 51.31924699875957,
  3009: 24.78894585681497,
  3010: 26.432661518392234,
  3011: 27.89357450514707,
  3012: 26.970093749475357,
  3013: 21.02569280936871,
  3014: 22.12185950151961,
  3015: 24.613641261417587,
  3016: 25.715621215314442,
  3017: 20.139338471731005,
  3018: 63.43726789834157,
  3019: 21.95660274621662,
  3020: 17.57150775922831,
  3021: 22.799002514857296,
  3022: 24.30947115457631,
  3023: 38.78531176909338,
  3024: 17.317025774559223,
  3025: 58.05633075980396,
  3026: 22.40120591638024,
  3027: 16.474196259602476,
  3028: 23.008901508439322,
  3029: 27.052166772402355,
  3030: 16.268267289546664,
  3031: 20.59541270567702,
  3032: 17.576224362281536,
  3033: 21.162922416273123,
  3034: 20.499085680087386,
  3035: 19.494097962357998,
  3036: 24.13206179697415,
  3037: 16.269648726284363,
  3038: 48.58762227953283,
  3039: 29.551299737023633,
  3040: 26.101254128007504,
  3041: 17.317268318386706,
  3042: 32.46629758875325,
  3043: 24.71571228307016,
  3044: 19.35706170986814,
  3045: 20.560136479143942,
  3046: 22.001499305559744,
  3047: 21.59796331294092,
  3048: 23.676277388534153,
  3049: 22.501793272127696,
  3050: 20.94671604929895,
  3051: 15.38574393944058,
  3052: 19.575009700744143,
  3053: 28.646232828103965,
  3054: 27.322101993118178,
  3055: 23.720573186908574,
  3056: 16.074319565349974,
  3057: 33.32134722818074,
  3058: 20.285122238374313,
  3059: 22.295064706926176,
  3060: 34.490917532259495,
  3061: 18.106393765182247,
  3062: 26.079044677691964,
  3063: 21.398745617756557,
  3064: 22.823506303815478,
  3065: 18.47791054171732,
  3066: 24.859219981415045,
  3067: 26.198412760892914,
  3068: 20.267591262597996,
  3069: 21.82305211316018,
  3070: 19.27636620134337,
  3071: 17.478282160164976,
  3072: 19.952696824307043,
  3073: 22.913364440080308,
  3074: 37.76115790007609,
  3075: 20.85346866691609,
  3076: 23.228780193503226,
  3077: 25.50770800398135,
  3078: 154.64968647259533,
  3079: 21.422578662230222,
  3080: 24.966601024976427,
  3081: 25.426154717908243,
  3082: 21.116805232982372,
  3083: 22.632575463152595,
  3084: 22.886517089084677,
  3085: 24.277410967593962,
  3086: 15.699314600829556,
  3087: 22.958603899109278,
  3088: 22.044843305150188,
  3089: 27.56220569609949,
  3090: 43.980673572995606,
  3091: 22.423081772021522,
  3092: 27.182357473367507,
  3093: 33.67803424641848,
  3094: 20.41465981033934,
  3095: 27.248095301815784,
  3096: 22.86151676393441,
  3097: 23.268617642017404,
  3098: 68.30071743446726,
  3099: 26.266923213663986,
  3100: 21.769676487112715,
  3101: 26.287161783054863,
  3102: 18.055580530943597,
  3103: 26.22059105155836,
  3104: 61.651085035714864,
  3105: 57.59925321337013,
  3106: 25.402073418775522,
  3107: 21.87121677749159,
  3108: 23.959520969025416,
  3109: 22.931472901999985,
  3110: 30.664410550165773,
  3111: 24.456447796217944,
  3112: 23.963950839818253,
  3113: 20.494624094194613,
  3114: 24.446386632345067,
  3115: 20.48368219481315,
  3116: 19.036299549814817,
  3117: 41.615518443890416,
  3118: 21.147150668316563,
  3119: 31.580201171143877,
  3120: 19.157016835209966,
  3121: 32.43860010051985,
  3122: 21.260052352198407,
  3123: 22.170805953238176,
  3124: 21.47586064345611,
  3125: 16.90389006567038,
  3126: 22.735171593017142,
  3127: 16.030681426522698,
  3128: 21.652106292110908,
  3129: 18.12806740305722,
  3130: 29.811987353964653,
  3131: 24.43197355182225,
  3132: 21.90778400548135,
  3133: 28.86605821502271,
  3134: 20.112216725955758,
  3135: 23.761281501081843,
  3136: 25.22139920463274,
  3137: 15.203177547688275,
  3138: 30.422763374825394,
  3139: 22.157386112211423,
  3140: 21.69372169366369,
  3141: 21.810987026660584,
  3142: 20.723168500268393,
  3143: 27.74449055745851,
  3144: 24.904457630647638,
  3145: 22.047822385472085,
  3146: 25.01832066089211,
  3147: 22.018276137680388,
  3148: 20.088413342959406,
  3149: 15.993445041072682,
  3150: 21.71371374209615,
  3151: 16.082029619197886,
  3152: 32.05792895322328,
  3153: 17.744407819978754,
  3154: 55.70427987538514,
  3155: 18.362794732645142,
  3156: 22.64426608839357,
  3157: 29.113946969552394,
  3158: 26.757012356152508,
  3159: 25.762261983367296,
  3160: 19.34709788938167,
  3161: 24.18484307769119,
  3162: 22.553476113759842,
  3163: 30.50485094832699,
  3164: 20.694598474306886,
  3165: 28.184680719605062,
  3166: 32.459182537984894,
  3167: 31.03834684697883,
  3168: 24.236856644856644,
  3169: 20.951297414339873,
  3170: 29.06696754419465,
  3171: 18.314385153991775,
  3172: 26.670006256595457,
  3173: 32.33484052517219,
  3174: 35.17548961043394,
  3175: 19.433655030843994,
  3176: 23.426508811737975,
  3177: 29.836281671110537,
  3178: 17.52731479901806,
  3179: 29.664620835401056,
  3180: 27.53450923102898,
  3181: 16.15156454873936,
  3182: 24.047066063357363,
  3183: 24.328812884327533,
  3184: 28.77066063308311,
  3185: 21.294756750733153,
  3186: 32.30092596611739,
  3187: 22.365458703849463,
  3188: 17.71897199732507,
  3189: 20.694747276268178,
  3190: 28.30708238799532,
  3191: 24.550369980039946,
  3192: 22.473263779819728,
  3193: 46.206823904042665,
  3194: 22.84565111792051,
  3195: 24.693088499018018,
  3196: 21.35567940577615,
  3197: 21.772696582437742,
  3198: 15.381351647852547,
  3199: 24.190579213521115,
  3200: 16.39477909929456,
  3201: 17.65643552693443,
  3202: 27.339659660966703,
  3203: 39.5147899418398,
  3204: 18.573252606961827,
  3205: 22.956243874401025,
  3206: 21.30509167881524,
  3207: 18.657391730118253,
  3208: 33.73258147365398,
  3209: 30.563833421719643,
  3210: 14.799722137924599,
  3211: 26.10835192010799,
  3212: 25.761074251010914,
  3213: 25.5305889925765,
  3214: 27.366421153974805,
  3215: 30.298344119217862,
  3216: 20.21500703752887,
  3217: 18.943906561450262,
  3218: 11.110380896712302,
  3219: 21.602907461113226,
  3220: 21.65778690532797,
  3221: 25.092031980476886,
  3222: 22.168242703458173,
  3223: 34.13360960521324,
  3224: 32.85419435056053,
  3225: 24.95964964821845,
  3226: 20.566832343882457,
  3227: 28.902688495336445,
  3228: 25.68032188536316,
  3229: 21.91925322608175,
  3230: 21.74823459622609,
  3231: 30.199148817991183,
  3232: 19.802908344937737,
  3233: 72.59672195495457,
  3234: 19.000731682483977,
  3235: 26.08083305484179,
  3236: 28.172938187947793,
  3237: 28.54592307929016,
  3238: 20.61187922938536,
  3239: 21.439840751993195,
  3240: 24.809915948089255,
  3241: 20.258818907270747,
  3242: 30.82223837747568,
  3243: 21.46849677120921,
  3244: 43.833305153367945,
  3245: 21.48131003434437,
  3246: 18.704356682930246,
  3247: 30.981368592151796,
  3248: 20.74497628133169,
  3249: 25.572729645076663,
  3250: 21.97903261637823,
  3251: 26.41325760933552,
  3252: 25.02905658014098,
  3253: 22.048768823153416,
  3254: 20.405114990567906,
  3255: 26.939996555490225,
  3256: 23.65320440065122,
  3257: 18.681780153173904,
  3258: 19.91990654962736,
  3259: 24.95133883909782,
  3260: 25.224840307263932,
  3261: 22.256798776962746,
  3262: 37.509249463074326,
  3263: 21.592171534041086,
  3264: 24.57329324708115,
  3265: 18.380544415863604,
  3266: 114.30061290307707,
  3267: 69.23295048182472,
  3268: 23.86837415915518,
  3269: 18.524515595838597,
  3270: 14.749481631515712,
  3271: 23.434258303343587,
  3272: 25.45163835536971,
  3273: 23.821170738593644,
  3274: 29.17663302640461,
  3275: 22.54226873382749,
  3276: 18.86399020878391,
  3277: 19.484587514274928,
  3278: 29.477312389168006,
  3279: 27.23898018937548,
  3280: 24.509014800261028,
  3281: 22.87586294995894,
  3282: 21.524909738378014,
  3283: 22.966663902396125,
  3284: 26.199036200324002,
  3285: 17.056243489245443,
  3286: 14.603747715576533,
  3287: 31.391293489119196,
  3288: 21.187947739013048,
  3289: 19.30100760747643,
  3290: 25.669018196775824,
  3291: 20.767744872752417,
  3292: 19.994813234291026,
  3293: 28.324963399397674,
  3294: 89.93470842348952,
  3295: 28.647004367984742,
  3296: 26.358872247057036,
  3297: 22.442202294030963,
  3298: 21.686355650880145,
  3299: 28.114631449515684,
  3300: 22.739398305378515,
  3301: 26.75059398849741,
  3302: 32.54167844768572,
  3303: 22.56411117410378,
  3304: 23.573119890554537,
  3305: 25.199720515052917,
  3306: 21.345180653214243,
  3307: 27.341241105735918,
  3308: 117.38463505412976,
  3309: 29.46200537533208,
  3310: 24.73514038960689,
  3311: 59.342760274246544,
  3312: 20.20119605118326,
  3313: 18.97279682573434,
  3314: 76.3083779165505,
  3315: 19.336077484297142,
  3316: 19.382313787306277,
  3317: 41.11746447704792,
  3318: 23.25954033909042,
  3319: 16.561841804706557,
  3320: 26.11488152513921,
  3321: 21.972389475723073,
  3322: 13.3484253662771,
  3323: 17.71502840090667,
  3324: 37.030297670378474,
  3325: 18.979545174265613,
  3326: 14.563231176914432,
  3327: 14.071220581679503,
  3328: 24.582873740884402,
  3329: 16.249786832275948,
  3330: 20.8743784683285,
  3331: 23.417316001858108,
  3332: 25.790912040097076,
  3333: 24.26677305840325,
  3334: 39.74392359098732,
  3335: 22.57573851125257,
  3336: 23.804236343256964,
  3337: 25.35855648456175,
  3338: 22.660598726926484,
  3339: 26.324218000154065,
  3340: 17.71584115267611,
  3341: 25.878527486449155,
  3342: 30.860662815823805,
  3343: 22.449525974655188,
  3344: 50.66587340148203,
  3345: 21.177853030962115,
  3346: 14.712591426646243,
  3347: 28.677919083705824,
  3348: 15.92788516771436,
  3349: 40.15212384794048,
  3350: 21.662867761976756,
  3351: 39.342084055309584,
  3352: 22.603215231509417,
  3353: 21.48806375218102,
  3354: 22.66197343974102,
  3355: 22.321933646622515,
  3356: 23.84235241970662,
  3357: 14.121553043234858,
  3358: 23.486901283020988},
 'sat_norm': {2926: 1.0141303475223522,
  2927: 0.9733236215139842,
  2928: 0.9756554174237216,
  2929: 1.0099207357530506,
  2930: 0.9975761719630378,
  2931: 1.0129096910475675,
  2932: 0.9786926801475617,
  2933: 0.9908656373164296,
  2934: 0.9970394923514415,
  2935: 1.005674002082544,
  2936: 1.005021497284611,
  2937: 1.0161199804756804,
  2938: 1.0363069106614862,
  2939: 0.9806810927639837,
  2940: 1.0063564631328514,
  2941: 0.9825850865776511,
  2942: 0.9732562949008152,
  2943: 1.0269564194628276,
  2944: 1.003094925512918,
  2945: 0.9671167933414888,
  2946: 1.0013530987500987,
  2947: 1.012620053099494,
  2948: 0.945333204962046,
  2949: 0.9493019269069891,
  2950: 1.0243869876691205,
  2951: 0.9875776394419525,
  2952: 1.014226704779202,
  2953: 1.1441733309012085,
  2954: 1.0098306860788355,
  2955: 1.0112540732797426,
  2956: 1.0009007298514452,
  2957: 1.0031269217775836,
  2958: 1.0278161268448935,
  2959: 1.0281457445784514,
  2960: 1.0115302001302269,
  2961: 0.9467480202845605,
  2962: 0.986573840734246,
  2963: 1.0141667144051463,
  2964: 0.9919068941896825,
  2965: 1.0085470311595268,
  2966: 1.0239054729248376,
  2967: 1.020538594058465,
  2968: 0.9948037348335896,
  2969: 1.0000969952813026,
  2970: 0.9919358997157075,
  2971: 0.9865637322024756,
  2972: 0.9998144518254726,
  2973: 1.0384452044441854,
  2974: 1.0080621690463638,
  2975: 1.0038839891742648,
  2976: 0.7143700621007412,
  2977: 1.0116723180512366,
  2978: 1.002079892535924,
  2979: 0.9808321216512758,
  2980: 1.0087935611047916,
  2981: 0.9932734337994568,
  2982: 1.056053132112779,
  2983: 1.0090579395241217,
  2984: 1.043154291417837,
  2985: 0.9891474778026144,
  2986: 1.0078760421110455,
  2987: 1.0390994458808522,
  2988: 1.021500184811433,
  2989: 0.9820169306265438,
  2990: 0.9847542241091106,
  2991: 1.0023197357830598,
  2992: 0.9881497088210198,
  2993: 1.0007942255306042,
  2994: 0.9868521740426361,
  2995: 0.9976319230889843,
  2996: 0.9808259808345197,
  2997: 1.0089515333435197,
  2998: 1.0388564015901953,
  2999: 1.0394318308487667,
  3000: 0.989429503084552,
  3001: 0.9729318292767275,
  3002: 0.9830549449800551,
  3003: 1.0063864670370668,
  3004: 1.0094163115130153,
  3005: 1.0072721007183743,
  3006: 0.9727134576379306,
  3007: 1.0233183713752592,
  3008: 0.932454854069319,
  3009: 0.9597686813204497,
  3010: 0.9627794479131333,
  3011: 0.9917068792359007,
  3012: 0.9747526520274972,
  3013: 1.0141702137648954,
  3014: 1.014375552871234,
  3015: 0.9973514732748298,
  3016: 1.0189635513949493,
  3017: 1.0266619196435436,
  3018: 0.8471464234451554,
  3019: 1.0065018442787594,
  3020: 1.0340011514739993,
  3021: 0.9964158870473083,
  3022: 0.9994329413763793,
  3023: 0.9380893107563972,
  3024: 1.0314589385302961,
  3025: 0.9584379372366154,
  3026: 0.9812911761201308,
  3027: 1.0154804233431014,
  3028: 1.0101418402805526,
  3029: 0.9697313644706408,
  3030: 1.0151844864590378,
  3031: 1.0036140875531898,
  3032: 0.987943163247401,
  3033: 1.0197577854655344,
  3034: 0.9949138790602514,
  3035: 0.9833904881428734,
  3036: 0.9919522877223199,
  3037: 1.0194947057939645,
  3038: 0.9703447923705733,
  3039: 0.9702700724674647,
  3040: 1.0282465855979164,
  3041: 1.017466431937713,
  3042: 0.9928694050785625,
  3043: 0.9910825382272067,
  3044: 1.0330519034453245,
  3045: 1.0039855182355626,
  3046: 1.0098247317118265,
  3047: 1.0077325171119162,
  3048: 1.0044331430802456,
  3049: 0.9871031077662732,
  3050: 0.9897538066893986,
  3051: 1.0103725841205573,
  3052: 0.9990409444596519,
  3053: 0.9876800873389653,
  3054: 0.9758922018190354,
  3055: 1.0014742094897284,
  3056: 1.0035091361638322,
  3057: 0.9838085247652458,
  3058: 1.0324769301777101,
  3059: 0.9906743386008047,
  3060: 0.9504471794150507,
  3061: 1.0214437719465888,
  3062: 1.0231471558963123,
  3063: 1.0091898090203377,
  3064: 1.007219705537996,
  3065: 1.0181935167382057,
  3066: 1.0084485272843648,
  3067: 0.9977873991311219,
  3068: 0.9967063344866722,
  3069: 1.0186555698079751,
  3070: 1.018630434959776,
  3071: 1.021904062955003,
  3072: 1.0038671326334654,
  3073: 1.0110088914060436,
  3074: 0.9550648309154123,
  3075: 1.0151474203285722,
  3076: 0.9912388582975302,
  3077: 0.9974003801209015,
  3078: 0.9394204743269104,
  3079: 1.005659568554309,
  3080: 0.9852669193908853,
  3081: 0.9868414518060851,
  3082: 1.008418877114411,
  3083: 1.0155361568887487,
  3084: 1.0163444551086582,
  3085: 0.9815060100511532,
  3086: 1.0312826057574334,
  3087: 1.019050022069666,
  3088: 1.0210705312581263,
  3089: 0.9845063655532027,
  3090: 0.9956603434183819,
  3091: 0.9832381568459375,
  3092: 1.0139603153817711,
  3093: 0.969489031901066,
  3094: 1.033757750127164,
  3095: 1.0050231720334837,
  3096: 1.006667766280241,
  3097: 1.0183940525012933,
  3098: 0.9491040222759595,
  3099: 1.0076861164968869,
  3100: 0.9996641797885922,
  3101: 1.0006074369267401,
  3102: 1.00972774629545,
  3103: 1.0270963349754274,
  3104: 0.9578333819209311,
  3105: 0.9714466624884867,
  3106: 0.9885666579064941,
  3107: 1.0113010683219383,
  3108: 0.9992319843784885,
  3109: 1.0004114000629347,
  3110: 1.0138193134401572,
  3111: 1.006525085430953,
  3112: 0.9944118135791852,
  3113: 1.0186248614348443,
  3114: 1.0100135704518438,
  3115: 1.0091167506686884,
  3116: 1.0098806293834064,
  3117: 0.9638557045122921,
  3118: 1.015999870812841,
  3119: 0.9627211115036184,
  3120: 1.0087350427391857,
  3121: 0.9874160935778596,
  3122: 1.0225543680510218,
  3123: 1.0079063171036888,
  3124: 1.009207512327152,
  3125: 0.9911900450767311,
  3126: 1.0236423911979284,
  3127: 0.9355345302307398,
  3128: 0.9985208867670423,
  3129: 1.039289993692001,
  3130: 1.017210237206265,
  3131: 0.9917957615233663,
  3132: 1.003469245023657,
  3133: 0.9908919836132267,
  3134: 1.0137446237364158,
  3135: 1.0147146915697012,
  3136: 0.9962164948924936,
  3137: 0.9755251652614582,
  3138: 1.0135421611010074,
  3139: 0.9925919359103554,
  3140: 1.0214117482048786,
  3141: 1.0162174369083532,
  3142: 1.045039420099494,
  3143: 0.9929976040669614,
  3144: 1.0078929813053041,
  3145: 1.0163671481359722,
  3146: 1.015541542290005,
  3147: 0.9977986941330688,
  3148: 1.038936954445572,
  3149: 1.0062450535988476,
  3150: 1.0241468132695184,
  3151: 1.0091264383157252,
  3152: 0.9968249355229285,
  3153: 1.0236429627787256,
  3154: 0.9884238689893099,
  3155: 1.0045248968201304,
  3156: 1.0035902601720472,
  3157: 1.0419174689892226,
  3158: 0.9940255154909493,
  3159: 0.9915571768309088,
  3160: 1.0307126423593933,
  3161: 1.0011391040200328,
  3162: 1.0204008518722099,
  3163: 1.0072359051911859,
  3164: 1.0221929739190083,
  3165: 0.9893786302985169,
  3166: 1.0054664881635087,
  3167: 1.0087972980055206,
  3168: 1.0138161095745575,
  3169: 1.006951808103303,
  3170: 0.9855570364965628,
  3171: 1.0124769347288143,
  3172: 0.9978266101761321,
  3173: 0.9820386627159355,
  3174: 0.9730491465706549,
  3175: 1.0131329941614906,
  3176: 0.998977323279894,
  3177: 0.991004673628124,
  3178: 1.0143260607788298,
  3179: 0.9850690318852628,
  3180: 0.9754302114147768,
  3181: 1.0060292056464113,
  3182: 0.9917660368872498,
  3183: 1.0154681519605495,
  3184: 0.9877362591474242,
  3185: 1.002035518029517,
  3186: 1.0178364954249204,
  3187: 0.9958208080764865,
  3188: 0.998427014161952,
  3189: 0.9831493142733162,
  3190: 1.0162802077034454,
  3191: 1.0188797765616566,
  3192: 1.018053134612317,
  3193: 0.9779787170153746,
  3194: 1.013345549254806,
  3195: 0.995554419429607,
  3196: 1.0166991661373845,
  3197: 1.0120416698486867,
  3198: 1.0028411553941103,
  3199: 1.0100837947558672,
  3200: 1.069457715568812,
  3201: 1.0172925185264403,
  3202: 1.011646090105101,
  3203: 0.9560110932514179,
  3204: 1.0345736365212173,
  3205: 1.0206104843474877,
  3206: 1.018053409627741,
  3207: 1.0156738634417932,
  3208: 0.9817767220312413,
  3209: 1.0200223585848587,
  3210: 1.0188525480999504,
  3211: 1.0054994185083415,
  3212: 1.002683933261818,
  3213: 1.0236818854994811,
  3214: 1.007368835431748,
  3215: 0.9782865710754324,
  3216: 1.0104499346418758,
  3217: 1.023077999441143,
  3218: 0.9511440757163485,
  3219: 1.0424620452080224,
  3220: 1.0166646841587217,
  3221: 1.0035343229363516,
  3222: 1.0125080592896738,
  3223: 1.0278911167195315,
  3224: 0.9837879385237469,
  3225: 0.9870441337245563,
  3226: 1.0235873161729394,
  3227: 0.98626397530318,
  3228: 1.0267446488796739,
  3229: 1.0174123408298898,
  3230: 1.0220290988911735,
  3231: 0.9766229121500949,
  3232: 1.0086748272798103,
  3233: 0.9506074288899843,
  3234: 1.0204996895032703,
  3235: 0.997829832527079,
  3236: 0.9952501855170656,
  3237: 1.004598925882593,
  3238: 0.9974787334905555,
  3239: 0.9873676631264109,
  3240: 1.0067858410094161,
  3241: 1.0363408093505184,
  3242: 1.0089611853203955,
  3243: 1.0410005419204813,
  3244: 0.9585431825281677,
  3245: 1.0081400264367142,
  3246: 1.0185656307978936,
  3247: 0.9648093042080965,
  3248: 1.0313744189892313,
  3249: 1.0152042063988844,
  3250: 1.020581833964678,
  3251: 1.013291879449966,
  3252: 1.0079281115972072,
  3253: 0.9892044703451868,
  3254: 1.031096675811666,
  3255: 1.0026408625958703,
  3256: 1.0120437396910644,
  3257: 1.025232111592093,
  3258: 1.0379760468945358,
  3259: 0.9786125413157207,
  3260: 0.9959091854575318,
  3261: 1.0126641925726607,
  3262: 0.9743717476406139,
  3263: 1.0188101420626527,
  3264: 1.0012276009917116,
  3265: 1.0040871089301262,
  3266: 0.9392602249783046,
  3267: 0.983829253352768,
  3268: 0.992114714380098,
  3269: 1.0428091969879487,
  3270: 1.000307011002834,
  3271: 0.9794156977776604,
  3272: 1.0072361553783307,
  3273: 0.9954123545611961,
  3274: 1.003138268199814,
  3275: 0.9965033247038982,
  3276: 1.0206345512918558,
  3277: 1.003002521323832,
  3278: 0.9880242666026517,
  3279: 1.0059751708303641,
  3280: 0.9953442087231883,
  3281: 1.0182931842148588,
  3282: 0.990191088298836,
  3283: 0.9923357799685764,
  3284: 0.9979056198697677,
  3285: 0.997596869313116,
  3286: 0.9997538825191563,
  3287: 0.9855305159643193,
  3288: 1.0128441941830526,
  3289: 1.0171713174154866,
  3290: 0.7575820632799466,
  3291: 1.0154779279271842,
  3292: 1.02069786720892,
  3293: 0.9935013258815747,
  3294: 0.9184967126009492,
  3295: 1.0355893001381864,
  3296: 1.0096255735211481,
  3297: 1.0084226444409494,
  3298: 1.0164623046255579,
  3299: 0.9832326054673819,
  3300: 1.0383577722930373,
  3301: 0.9936645827103061,
  3302: 0.9602723779198662,
  3303: 0.9820694743141144,
  3304: 0.9940047435846677,
  3305: 1.0140614637216978,
  3306: 1.0120142759365873,
  3307: 0.9905071379223702,
  3308: 0.9438369749069927,
  3309: 1.0002752796336467,
  3310: 1.0093766088107514,
  3311: 0.9670898290141468,
  3312: 1.0045156345403943,
  3313: 1.012429906660854,
  3314: 0.9791792080756015,
  3315: 1.0215928327278807,
  3316: 1.0333163307198283,
  3317: 0.9676163363302263,
  3318: 0.9957421909542972,
  3319: 1.0032599015206682,
  3320: 0.986158119941354,
  3321: 1.008978645477572,
  3322: 0.9415913535999383,
  3323: 1.0010661362135909,
  3324: 0.9733693780374557,
  3325: 1.0034974061916457,
  3326: 0.9766707493084783,
  3327: 1.0134776833282058,
  3328: 0.982400518650049,
  3329: 1.0157290616233774,
  3330: 1.0230188328338625,
  3331: 1.004055741432238,
  3332: 1.004437034400667,
  3333: 1.014322735968237,
  3334: 0.9589800961037205,
  3335: 0.9946417081016445,
  3336: 0.9928025066700812,
  3337: 1.0072666900782712,
  3338: 1.0052413456023908,
  3339: 0.9840790908456806,
  3340: 1.0460434368869298,
  3341: 1.0071367841640988,
  3342: 0.9899278682622145,
  3343: 0.9914638436015157,
  3344: 0.9286181080089225,
  3345: 1.0038999848854375,
  3346: 0.9603877551330975,
  3347: 0.9954584117385712,
  3348: 1.021201681499136,
  3349: 0.9760175570504956,
  3350: 0.994474734749421,
  3351: 0.9896642647790318,
  3352: 1.0039526663933331,
  3353: 0.9969554739928349,
  3354: 1.0015332166974644,
  3355: 0.9956318753512245,
  3356: 0.9955873808781457,
  3357: 1.0144012026991114,
  3358: 0.9980261364004839}})
```

I cannot reproduce this error using a sample data set, so I figure it is something with the y data.

I can however get the correct kde plot if it's 1D

This code gives me

```
sns.kdeplot(data=df, x='sat_norm')
```

[image]

Comment: Your 2nd plot is not reproducible: see [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT8xw.png). Tested in `seaborn 0.12.1` and `matplotlib 3.6.2`. The kdeplots in the margins are properly scaled. I'm voting to close this as not reproducible.

Comment: Ok, I think somewhere else in my code I must be doing something to the data or changing a setting on seaborn, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems switching X and Y worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35031319)